# How to obtain the "id" of the Page which is shown in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have various pages in html like this

```
<body onload="init()">

<div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Here is the index page.</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
<p><center>Below you may transition to our other pages.</center></p>

<a href="#about" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" data-inline="true">About  Me</a>
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="about">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>About Us</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
<a href="#home" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Back Home</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Now i need to grab the id of the page which is shown currently... How to do that?

Comment: I know nothing about jquery mobile but maybe `$('div[data-role=page]')[0].attr("id")` will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried: `$.mobile.activePage.attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

Any of these:

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page").ui-page-active').attr('id');

$('.ui-page-active').attr('id');
```

should also do.